# AngularJS push not updating the value in one div while updating in other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

If I'm adding a new contact, its getting added in ul - li but not in select - option.

This is my program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Hello World, AngularJS - ViralPatel.net</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function ContactController($scope) 
    {
        $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

        $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.newcontact = "";
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
    <select ID="select-add-new-product-brand-name">
        <option  ng-model="selectedItem" ng-repeat="contact in contacts" value={{contact}}>{{ contact|uppercase }}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ContactController">
     Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newcontact"/>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
    </ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are being Two controlling

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AYpLKA0omsqaDorGasjE?p=preview)

just use one controller

```
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
    <select ID="select-add-new-product-brand-name">
        <option  ng-model="selectedItem" ng-repeat="contact in contacts" value={{contact}}>{{ contact|uppercase }}</option>
    </select>
     Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newcontact"/>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: But the requirement is such that these two DIV to be displayed at the same time.

Comment: what do you mean by "two Div to be displayed at the same time"?

Comment: Actually I have 2 different DIVs, only one will be visible at a time. but both will have different elements but contacts list is common in both. so i want when a new contact is added, it should be available in both the cases.

Comment: If your elements are within the same scope, it doesn't matter if they are visible or not.  If you want to manage 2 separate scopes/controllers you will want to share a service between them like - http://plnkr.co/edit/xf803TfFIXrVKsnpai1e?p=preview